# access server side method in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have method in aspx.cs page,i want to access this method in .aspx page in javascript function after change event of selectbox as when selectbox option is change the change value to pass to aspx.cs page's method.And bind that value to another selectbox with that values came from web service.

Comment: Sounds like you want `AutoPostBack = True`.

Comment: You either have to do a postback, or make an Ajax-request.

Comment: Is this WebForms or MVC?

Comment: @jayu When you say selectbox, are you talking about a `DropDownList` or a `ListBox`?

Answer (score 2):

You can access a server-side OnCheckChanged method handler by either using an UpdatePanel and defining this control an AsyncPostBackTrigger and also using AutoPostback="True" or by using the [WebMethod() attribute](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to define an Async method in the page and then using jQuery/Javascript to perform the request.

Comment: I'd prefer WebMethod attribute and calling it from JavaScript, using PageMethods.

Comment: it give's error message as 'PageMethods' is undefined

Comment: Be sure your page Imports System.Web.Services ... that will (hopefully) resolve the issue.  Also, be sure the syntax is <WebMethod()> _ not <PageMethod()> _

Answer (score 0):

To access a server side method inside a javascript function following needs to be covered:

1)The code behind method has to have the attribute of “**WebMethod**” and should be a static method.

2)ScriptManager has to be added inside the form tag.

3)*PageMethods.* to call the code behind method.

Code behind snippet:

```
[Webmethod]
Public static IamServerMethod()
{
//Your logic goes here
}
```

ASPX file snippet:

Add script Manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Inside the Javascript function:

```
Function IamJavascriptFunction()
{
PageMethods. IamServerMethod();
}
```